# Php for nested loop

Tags: php, for-loop

please someone can explain me in detailed way how this loop in php works?

```
for($a=1;$a<10;$a++) 
{
    echo "<br>";

    for ($b=0;$b<$a;$b++)
    echo $a;

}
```

Why the output is 
1 
22
333
4444 
55555 etc
and not just 1 2 3 4 5 and so on, i know is something elementary but i cannot get it.

thank you.

Comment: You're expecting the output to be `1 2 3 4 5`?

Answer (score 6):

The key is the `$a` in the inner loop.

```
for ($b=0;$b<$a;$b++) 
             ^-------------- HERE
```

this will count from zero to `$a` (which is increased every time) in every loop and output `$a` as many times.

```
 $a = 0:  no output (inner loop runs from 0 to 0)
 $a = 1:  1 output  (inner loop runs from 0 to 1)
 $a = 2:  2 outputs (inner loop runs from 0 to 2)
 $a = 3:  3 output  (inner loop runs from 0 to 3)
 etc.....
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two loops in your code, the outer loop initialize the value of $a as 1

```
$a = 1;
```

Then in the inner loop $b is set to 0

```
$b = 0;
```

The condition for the inner loop to succeed in its first execution is

```
$b < $a
```

Or if you don't follow it,

```
0 < 1
```

Because remember the inner loop initialize $b as 0, and $a is initialized in the outer loop as 1

So 0 is less that 1, so it will succeed and execute

```
echo $a; // 1
```

The inner loop will only execute it 1 time because in its second iteration $b is already 1

```
$b++
```

Now it will go to the outer loop again, and $a will equal to 2 because the for loop just did

```
$a++
```

2 is less than 10 so it will execute the second loop again. But now the second loop is condition changes because

```
$b < $a // 0 < 2
```

Because remember $a is now equal to 2! So the condition succeed and it will execute

```
echo $a // or 2
```

Then after executing in its first try, the for loop will do $b++ so $b will become 1.

SO now, the for loop will test the condition again and the result will be

```
$b < $a // 1 < 2
```

1 is less than 2 so it will execute the echo statement again

```
echo $a // 2
```

Hence you get 22

Then after that the for loop will do $b++, so now $b is 2 already! Because 2 is not less than 2, hence it will fail and go to the outer loop again.

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the outer loop, the inner loop is performed `a` times. So 1 is echoed once, 2 is echoed twice, and so on.